# Solving a system of equalities in 4 variables (but no numeric constant)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have pairwise relatively prime positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ such that
$$
\frac{a-b}{4} = \frac{2a-9c}{7} = 27d-10a = 9c-2b = \frac{27d-10b}{41} = \frac{3d-5c}{4}  \tag{$\star$}
$$
and
$$
\frac{a+b}{3} = \frac{2(a+6c)}{7} = 2(7a-18d) = 2(6c-b) = \frac{2(7b+18d)}{41} = \frac{7c+3d}{4}.  \tag{$\star\star$}
$$

I know, *a priori*, that the problem I’m working on has exactly one solution $(a,b,c,d)=(29,1,1,11)$.

> **QUESTION #1:** Do ($\star$) and ($\star\star$), independently or together, provide enough information to find the exact numeric solution? Or even just prove $b=c$?
>
> **QUESTION #2:** If I can also provide, for each pair of variables, an equation of the form $pa^2+qab+rb^2+s=0$, where $p,q,r,s$ are integer constants, would *that* be enough information to find the exact solution?

I’ve tried everything I know how to throw at it, and just get caught going around in circles.

**EDIT #1:** Doing a brute-force computer search of pairwise relatively prime odd integers $a,b,c,d$ with $1 \le a \le 1001$ and $1 \le d \le \lceil \tfrac{7}{18}a \rceil$ and $1 \le c \le \lceil \tfrac{2}{9}a \rceil$ and $1 \le b \le a-2$ reveals a number of possible solutions… but adding in the one extra condition $3bd-ac=4$ reduces the set to the desired single solution.

**EDIT #2:** Expanding the search, there is a solution whenever $a$ is a Pell number $P_{12k-7}$.

---

Comment: Did you try Gaussian elimination?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: I _think_ so… but without any numerical constants, I keep getting caught in circles where I’m just reconfirming one or another of the parts of the equality chain.

Comment: OK check [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a-b%29%2F4%3D9c-2b%2C+%282a-9c%29%2F7%3D9c-2b%2C+27d-10a%3D9c-2b%2C+%2827d-10b%29%2F41%3D9c-2b%2C+%283d-5c%29%2F4%3D9c-2b) and [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%2Bb%29%2F3%3D2%286c-b%29%2C+%282%28a%2B6c%29%29%2F7%3D2%286c-b%29%2C+2%287a-18d%29%3D2%286c-b%29%2C+%282%287b%2B18d%29%29%2F41%3D2%286c-b%29%2C+%287c%2B3d%29%2F4%3D2%286c-b%29) (wolframalpha).

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: Yes, that just leaves $d$ as a free variable, which is what I found. I’m hoping to solve the system exactly. I guess I need more information.

Comment: $pa^2+qab+rb^2+s=0 \implies (2 a p + b q)^2 - (q^2 - 4 p r) b^2 = -4 p s$. If $(q^2 - 4 p r) >0$, then this Pell equation with (possible) infinite set solutions $(a,b)$. If  $(q^2 - 4 p r) <0$, then set solutions is finite.

Comment: System simplify as $(a,b,c,d)=(a,41 a - 108 d,8 a - 21 d,d)$

Comment: @DmitryEzhov: I’ll try putting that simplified "solution" through the six Pell equations and see if that helps.

Comment: I've just got $(\star)\iff (\star\star)\iff b=41a-108d$ and $c=8a-21d$.

Comment: @DmitryEzhov: Your comment about the Pell equation may have solved the problem! In particular, one of the Pell equations, after substitutions, revealed the constraint I needed to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Add condition $3bd-ac=4$ implies Pell equation for `(a,d)`: $(9 d - 2 a)^2 - 2 a^2 = -1$. Then `(a,b,c,d)`=`(29,1,1,11),(1136689,33461,38081,431211),...`

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{a-b}{4} = \frac{2a-9c}{7} = 27d-10a = 9c-2b = \frac{27d-10b}{41} = \frac{3d-5c}{4}  \tag{$(1)$}$

Above equation (1) has another numerical solution:

$(a,b,c,d)=(w,5w,w,3w)$

Where, $w=41$

Also above has,  $(a=c)$

Regarding the second simultaneous equation (2):

"OP" may have overlooked the fact, that since

there are four unknown's (a,b,c,d) and there are

six equations. Hence there are more equations than

unknown's. Hence the equations becomes redundant.

Comment: p.s. I didn’t overlook the "more equations than unknowns" fact: I just wanted to present all six possible pairings (_e.g._ $a$ with $b$, $a$ with $c$, _etc._).

Comment: By the way, this solution isn’t correct: $27d-10a = 27(3w)-10(w)=71w$.